# EPSON print receipt alignment issue

Tags: javascript, html, printers, thermal-printer, epson

I want to achieve proper alignment for my receipt, currently I can get the alignment like in the picture [currently getting the receipt like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8haZ.png)

To achieve proper alignment I tried two ways, In the single line I tried to mention both left alignment and right alignment, which did not work, as epson does not allow both alignment on the same line
Then I tried adding blank space between cash and amount, but sometime due to the longer description, amount can go further towards right, so its not stable, so can somebody tell me the right approach to achieve proper alignment

```
self.receiptText += alignLeft + tndrDesc + "\n";
self.receiptText += alignRight + formatTdrAmt + "\n";
```

but the above code gives the description in one line above the amount, but if I do not use the \n it will come in the same line without being aligned to right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to edit the character string of the print request by the application itself, not the function of the printer.

For example, suppose you want to print 32 columns.

- Apply [padEnd(32, ' ')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd) to the item name string.
- Gets the [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) of the price string.
- Extracts a string from the item name string with [substring (0, (32 - price string length))](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).
- Combine the extracted character string and price character string with [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) or [+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators), and then combine the new line code to create a character string for one line.

If each character is within the SBCS(Single Byte Character Set) range, you can get a print result with the same number of digits by requesting that character string to be printed.

---

Considering the added source.

In this case, `alignLeft` and `alignRight` are not required.

And instead of suddenly adding to `self.receiptText`, use working variables.

The process will be as follows.

```
printlineWork = tndrDesc + '                                  '; // 34 columns space character
printlineWork = printlineWork.substring(0, 34);
printlineWork += ('        ' + formatTdrAmt).slice(-8) + '\n'; // 8 columns space character
self.receiptText += printlineWork;
```

Adjust the digit position as desired.

Comment: Looks like it. In that case, you can simply combine it with a 32 digit blank string. Since it is cut out by substring() in the later processing, there is no problem even if it is long.

Comment: I am not able to understand the solution, could you  please elaborate. Currently my issue is i am not able to align tender type and amount in the same line, i tried with giving empty spaces, since i have multiple item descriptions(some are bigger in length) so its corresponding amount doesnt come under the same line, all i want is to restrict the right side amount in one fixed position, like i have 42 column in the receipt paper, so can i start printing the amount after like 35th position of the paper?

Comment: in other word, for the all the price amounts i want to start printing after 35th column(let it be fixed). can this be done?

Comment: I also don't know the details of your situation, so I'm writing an answer in outline. If you want to examine the process in detail, please add the program source of your printing process, the contents of the variables at the time of printing, etc. to your question article.